# Android WhatsApp api file(image) + caption

Tags: android

Is some one knows how can i share image or file via my application with text to whatsapp member?

```
String text = "Look at my`enter code here` awesome picture";
        Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("file://my_picture");
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myPicUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

I tried this one and it works great for any file that ends in .txt
It is great, but i just want to add an extra text to this message
Is it possible?